# Spark: How to convert from Dataset[String] back to good and old Dataframe

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have some legacy code using the `Dataframe` but now it needs to process `Dataset[String]`. At the moment I must make it work so I'm looking for a quick and easy way to convert from `Dataset[String]` to `Dataframe` so my method can work on it. Can anyone with Spark knowledge help?

Comment: What about `DataSet's` [toDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@toDF():org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alberto Bonsanto said in his comment, you can use the toDF method:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val ds = Seq("a", "b").toDS
val df = ds.toDF
```